# Executing Assembly File on Mac

Tags: assembly

(I'm using a Mac by the way)

So I just started learning Assembly, and I tried the following program:

```
section .text
global _start

_start:

mov edx, len
mov ecx, msg
mov ebx, 1
mov eax, 4
int 0x80

mov eax, 1
int 0x80

section .data

msg db  'Hello, world!',0xa
len equ $ - msg
```

I tried running it in Terminal:

```
gcc -o sieve sieve.s
```

But this gives me these errors:

```
sieve.s:1:no such instruction: `section .text'
sieve.s:2:no such instruction: `global _start'
sieve.s:6:too many memory references for `mov'
sieve.s:7:too many memory references for `mov'
sieve.s:8:too many memory references for `mov'
sieve.s:9:too many memory references for `mov'
sieve.s:10:suffix or operands invalid for `int'
sieve.s:12:too many memory references for `mov'
sieve.s:13:suffix or operands invalid for `int'
sieve.s:15:no such instruction: `section .data'
sieve.s:17:no such instruction: `msg db (72)ello,world!(44)0xa'
sieve.s:18:no such instruction: `len equ $-msg'
```

I'm guessing it's something to do with writing in the wrong version of the Assembly language or something, but I don't know much about the language, so I don't have a clue. Can anyone help?

Comment: The GNU assembler uses AT&T syntax by default. It is also less 'friendly' for standalone ASM programming. You might look as [nasm](http://www.nasm.us/). Or adapt the [example](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Assembler#Example_Programs).

Comment: @BrettHale Thanks for replying, I tried the example, and I got this error: ld: `library not found for -lcrt1.10.6.o
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status`

Comment: Replace all `_start` with `main`.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the hint given by Brett Hale (AT&T syntax) you'll have a second problem:

Each operating system has other mechanisms for calling the operating system's functions.

Interrupt "int 0x80" with arguments in registers is the way operating system functions are called in 32-bit Linux. Even 64-bit Linux uses a different method.

After converting your program to AT&T syntax (as far as I know new GCC variants even allow Intel syntax when using an additional line of code) your program will not work on MacOS because MacOS uses a different mechanism than "int 0x80" used in Linux.